# TypeScript type error with type string|number|null but not with string|number

Tags: typescript

Why does the function *foo* report an error `Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.` in the `return value;` line and the function *bar* works as expected?

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20foo(value%3A%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7C%20null)%3A%20string%20%7C%20null%20%7B%0D%0A%09if%20(typeof%20value%20!%3D%3D%20'string'%20%26%26%20value%20!%3D%3D%20null)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09throw%20new%20Error()%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%09return%20value%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20bar(value%3A%20string%20%7C%20number)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%09if%20(typeof%20value%20!%3D%3D%20'string')%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09throw%20new%20Error()%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%09return%20value%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

```
function foo(value: string | number | null): string | null {
    if (typeof value !== 'string' && value !== null) {
        throw new Error();
    }

    return value;
}

function bar(value: string | number): string {
    if (typeof value !== 'string') {
        throw new Error();
    }

    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't throw a type error in Typescript 3.2.2 with strict null checks.

```
function foo(value: string | number | null): string | null {
    //value has type `string | number | null`
    if (typeof value !== 'string' && /*value has type `number | null` */ value !== null) {
        //value has type `number`
        throw new Error();
    }
    //value has type `string | null`

    return value;
}
```

Comment: I would exactly expect the types that you described but I’m 100% sure that I get a type error in the TypeScript Playground. Did you test it with my shared url?

Comment: It looks like the key factor is enabling strict null checks.  It never really occurred to me that disabling strict null checking could actually cause type errors.  When strict null checking is disabled, both string and number are basically treated like 'nullable' types.  Therefore, checking for value !== null fails to isolate numbers in the type checking.

Comment: Actually quite confusing that without strict null checks a code that actually checks for null fails.